# How do i use a different header for each page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cms-pages

I'm new to Magento i have a bit of a problem i have 4 pages e.g home about etc... all these pages use the same header, i have created another header and updated in the page.xml file, from what i gathered the header and all the other stuff are being called from 1column.phtml. How do i do this so when you click a different page it can change header.

basically i want this code underneath to change when a different page is loaded.

```
<head>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
```

to

```
<head>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head-about') ?>
</head>
```

this is the part of the page.xml file which i have modified.

```
 <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
        </block>


                    <block type="page/html_header" name="header-about" as="header-about">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
        </block>
```

Comment: Better if you can share the page.xml - the modified section

Answer (score 2):

If you want to different header on CMS page then you can achieve by:

In `CMS->Design->Layout Update XML` put this code:

```
   <reference name="header">
    <block type="page/header" name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>cms/headers/about_us.phtml</template></action> 
    </block> 
</reference>
```

And create file `about_us.phtml` **your_theme/template/cms/headers**
It's done.

[For more see here.](https://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-change-the-header-of-magento-cms-page/)